# Does anyone know about Equazecapital.com?

Tags: trading

There is an investment company called Equaze Capital. I am wondering if it is legit or not.

Comment: Hi D Candy, requests for service reviews are not on-topic here, but you can check out the general advice in the two linked questions. They both seem related to your situation.

Comment: Given that the supposed photo of their CFO is a picture of a model taken from a book cover, I'm going to say they're a scam.